# 3D matrix averaring in matlab

Tags: matlab, mean

i have R 3d matrix,n varies from 1:100.
I have generated 20 such R matrix.
Now i have to average each  R for this 20 experiment. 
so that I'll get n,100 avg matrix.
How to average this 20, n Matrix?

I want to add(avg) all 20 times generated R for each n .I must have avg 100 R matrix .

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually have a 3D matrix `R`, it is very easy to average:

```
R = rand(3,4,5); %Suppose this is your matrix
```

Now you just need to pick the dimension you want to average in:

```
mean(R,1) %First dimension
mean(R,2) %Second  dimension
mean(R,3) %Third dimension
```

If you are not sure which one you need, just check the `size` of all three.

Comment: Thnx Dennis for you answer .but I want to add(avg) all 20 times generated R for each n .I must have n averaged R matrix .

Comment: @Vanita Sorry but I can't make much of your description. Could you perhaps show the code that you have now and give a small scale example including: 1. The inputs, 2. The result that you get now, 3. The result that you want to have.

Comment: thnx Dennis, i got the fault. i kept my avr veiable inside 1st loop.